# Errors in Razor pages cause server to hang

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've been writing an app using the awesome new Razor view engine and for the most part, things have been great.

One issue I keep running into, however, is that if I should happen to write invalid code, such as referencing a `null` property or even a non existent property, rather than throwing an error, something happens in the background that causes the browser to wait and wait and wait and if I do not cancel the browser's request quick enough, IIS will simply hang.

It seems as if it enters some sort of loop.  CPU usage goes up (though not terribly high) and restarting IIS via either GUI or `iisreset` command seems to take abnormally long (presumably while it waits for the process to safely shutdown).

This also happens for other invalid code scenarios such as failing to close a code block with a closing brace.

I notice this behavior on more than one machine.

Any ideas if this is a known issue or have I mis configured something?

Thanks!

Comment: That should not happen. Try attaching a debugger to check what it's doing.

Comment: Even with the VS2010 debugger attached, I can step through the controllers and into the views but when a problematic instruction is hit, it just stops processing and nothing happens - no error, nothing. The debugger itself continues running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.  I had installed a package via NuGet called "Razor Debugger" and apparently this plugin was intercepting Razor errors somehow, and was consequently not showing them.

Removing that package now allows Razor to work properly.  What a relief.

Steer clear of this library.

Comment: I had this problem too. Annoying